# Automapper can not convert type of object

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use automapper and got an exception.
Here are my classes:

```
public class Image : BaseEntity, IEntity<Guid>
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Photo")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class ImageDownloadResponse
{
    public ImageDownloadResponse(ImageMetaData metaData, Stream stream)
    {
        DownloadedImageMetadata = metaData;
        ImageByteStream = stream;
    }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public ImageMetaData DownloadedImageMetadata;
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream ImageByteStream;
}

[DataContract]
public class ImageMetaData
{
    public ImageMetaData(Guid imageId, string imageMimeType)
    {
        ImageId = imageId;
        ImageMimeType = imageMimeType;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "ImageId", Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public Guid ImageId;
    [DataMember(Name = "ImageMimeType", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public string ImageMimeType;
}
```

And automapper configuration for these classes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageDownloadResponse>()
     .ForCtorParam("metaData", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new ImageMetaData(src.Id, src.ImageMimeType)))
     .ForCtorParam("stream", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new MemoryStream(src.ImageData)))
     .ForSourceMember(src => src.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForSourceMember(src => src.Photo, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The exception details are that it can't convert from `System.Guid` to my entity Image.

But I didn't try to convert this field. I put ignore option. What's going on?

Comment: What does the constructor for ImageMetaData look like? I imagine the problem is that you're passing in the Image.Id, and it's expecting an Image.

Comment: @JonathonChase is it impossible to do that? So how can I replace automapper config then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do use `ConstructUsing`, like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageDownloadResponse>()
  .ConstructUsing(src => new ImageDownloadResponse(new ImageMetaData(src.Id, src.ImageMimeType), new MemoryStream(src.ImageData)))
```